# How to fix my model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to understand model associations, and how to have them set up correctly. I'm hoping someone here knows how, and that I can kind of explain what I want to accomplish.

I have a user model that looks like this:

```
has_many :companies
has_many :contacts
belongs_to :company
```

a user can create a company, and belongs to a company. It can also import contacts from email providers (such as Google). Thus it can have many contacts.

Then we have the company model:

```
belongs_to :admin, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
has_many :users
has_many :categories
has_many :contacts
```

a company belongs to an admin, which is the user that creates it.  It can also however have several users that belongs to the company (they get invited by the admin). It also has categories, that the admin can create - which belongs to the company. It can also have contacts, which will be put the content of the categories (the categories are groups for contacts).

Then we have the categories. They are created by the admin (user) for the company.

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :contacts
```

The categories store all the contacts.

Then lastly the contacts:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
```

The contacts belongs to the user (the user that imports them) however they are also a part of the assets to the company (as all the actions the user makes), they don't necessarily need to be a part of a category, however they can - and can also be a part of several categories.

I'm certain there are some flaws, and I want to fix my associations now so I don't end up building a lot of code on the wrong structure.

Hope somebody can help me out, on how to clean up this relatively large app, for a rookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change a few things:

1. In the `company` model, change `has_many :contacts` to `has_many :contacts, through: :categories`. It seems like `categories` only serve to group contacts together. And so therefore:
2. In the `contact` model, add `belongs_to :category` and remove `belongs_to :company`
3. `Users` and `contacts` do not have to be associated if a `user` wants to import `contacts`. I would either remove this association entirely if you don't need it or have a the same `has_many :categories` and `has_many :contacts, through: :categories` relationship as the `companies`. Of course, remove `belongs_to :user` in the contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into polymorphism. I'm doing something like this although I stripped out and and renamed a few things to more closely match your question. This is untested but might help illustrate a different approach

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :business_users
      has_many :businesses, :through => business_users   
      has_many :contacts, :through => :contact_users
      ...
    end

    class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :company
      has_many :categorizations, :as => :categorizeable
      has_many :categories,  -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, :through => :categorizations
      ...
    end

    class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :admin, :class_name => :User, :foreign_key => "user_id"
      has_many :company_users
      has_many :users, :through => :company_users
      has_many :categorizations, :as => :categorizeable
      has_many :categories,  -> { order(created_at: :desc) }, :through => :categorizations
      ...
    end

    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :categorizeable, polymorphic: true
      has_many :categorizations
      has_many :companies,  :through => :categorizations, :source => :categorized, :source_type => 'User'
      has_many :contacts,  :through => :categorizations, :source => :categorized, :source_type => 'Contact'
      ...
    end
```